# If $u_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, can I factor out $u_j$ in $u_j + A_j \sum_{j=1}^J A_j^Tu_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $u_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A_j \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where $n \neq m$, can I factor out $u_j$ in $$u_j + A_j \sum_{j=1}^J A_j^Tu_j?$$

Working it out myself, I think that

$$u_j + A_j \sum_{j=1}^J A_j^Tu_j \neq \left(I_{n \times n} - A_j \sum_{j=1}^J A_j^T\right)u_j$$

where $I_{n\times n}$ is an identity matrix. Is there some other way of pulling out the vector $u_j$?

Comment: Your 1st displayed equation is badly-written, as it uses $j$ as a dummy variable in the summation but also as a non-dummy variable outside the summation.

Comment: The first line is not an equation. And yes, $j$ is a dummy variable that is being summed over in $\sum_{j=1}^J A_j^Tu_j$. Then this vector is multiplied by $A_j$ and add $u_j$ to it.

Comment: But the $u_j$ in the summation isn't the same as the $u_j$ being added to the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation is tricky to read but I will answer what I think you mean.

So we'll identify (for simplicity of matrix multiplication) $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$ (the set of matrices with $n$ rows and 1 column). With this identification, we'll say $u \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $A \in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, what I'm assuming you're asking is if $u$ can somehow be factored out in the expression $$u + A A^T u.$$
Please correct me if this is not what you mean! The short answer is yes! Indeed, $AA^T \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and hence we can write this as
$$ I_n u + AA^T u = (I_n + AA^T)u $$
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: $j$ is a dummy variable that's being summed over.

Comment: Okay thanks, so are $u_j$ and $A_j$ just meant to be $u$ and $A$ respectively? You can't use the same variable in the same expression to mean two different things; it's too hard to understand otherwise.